# Wikipedia word2vec

Tags: gensim

I followed the example in this link and ran the following script to process the latest english wikipedia articles:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html

$ python -m gensim.scripts.make_wiki

The result of running the script after 9 hours is that I now have .mm and .txt files. I want to train a word2vec model but all the examples found start from the .bz2 file.

How do I train a word2vec model using the .mm files as input instead of the raw bz2 file? The link below shows how to train an LDA model. Can someone pls share syntax?

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html

Thanks!

Comment: PS. I am using this code now but wanted to come up with a quicker way since I already have the .mm files. Thanks!   [link] (https://github.com/hgrif/wiki-word2vec)